# Use template at root directory using Template Route Manager

Tags: templates, template-routes, template-manager

I use EE 2.10.1 and the Template Route Manager to show a specific template at the root of my site (e.g. `http://www.example.com/`).

My setup in the Template Route Manager resembles the screenshot:
[image]

I can open `/project`, `/imprint` a.s.o., but if I open the root `/` URL the template is not shown, but just an empty page.

If possible, I don't want to use the Pages modul to achieve that, as this is the only static page I have and it is hardcoded.

**How can I assign a template to the root of a page by using Template Route Manager?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. You also don't need to do that. The template file you are wanting to be your homepage is already called index.

http://www.ee2docs.com/cp/design/templates/new_template_group.html#default-home-page

Set your `site` template group as your default template group via this setting, and it automatically will make site/index your root.